# How to visualize the text layer in a pdf

Tags: pdf, ocr, pdftotext

I'm looking for a way to extract text and the position of that text from a PDF with a "text layer".
My goal is to show a PDF with the extracted text as a layer and to have the user select certain lines as areas of interest.

pdftotext only shows me the text in rows, but without position information.
I checked TET from PDFlib but they don't have a trial version and it doesn't seem like the libraries are actively maintained anymore.

The program should work on Linux

Comment: Great question! Did you ever find an answer? :\

Comment: Making *some* progress - https://stackoverflow.com/a/49306240/1021819 -> https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/1769 - but what OCR engine are you in fact using?

Comment: It was a very generic question, because I couldn't find a library etc. already providing this.